# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest not working on older Internet Explorer versions (access denied)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

A cross-domain XMLHttpRequest works on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE11.

IE9 crashes on IETester when I'm trying to test the site.

On IE8 the javascript error says "Access is denied" in line 36, char 3.

On IE7 the javascript error says "Access is denied" in line 37, char 3.

On IE6 the javascript error says "Permission denied" in line 37, char 3.

Some of the javascript:

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert('main');
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert('ie6 etc');
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,true);   // <-- Line 36
    xmlhttp.send();                 // <-- Line 37
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById(wrap_id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
```

This is from the php file it is requesting:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I'd like to get it working on IE8, etc, thanks.

Comment: Old versions of IE do not recognize CORS headers.

Comment: Is there any alternative javascript way of getting innerHTML from another website?

Comment: Browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/cors

Comment: @LukeWenke Post to your web server, have your web server make the cross domain request and return the result

Comment: It's meant to be a Javascript API where only one Javascript file is included on a site and then it creates DIVs etc and loads up the content. When you click on items it updates the DIV. I'm not sure if your suggestion fits that.

Comment: On cors it has a link to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx it says that for IE8 a XDomainRequest object can be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works....

```
if (window.XDomainRequest) {
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    if (xdr) {
        xdr.onload=function() {
            element.innerHTML = xdr.responseText;
        }
        xdr.open("get", URL, true);
        xdr.send();
    }
}
else {
    var xmlhttp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Javascript Code which I have used to resolve IE9, IE10 issue with xmlhttprequest while loading and parsing XML.

```
//New Flag for XDomainRequest is being used or Not
var isXDomain = false;
//Establish Reference to script
var self = this;
//Set Your XML Path here
var xml_link = "";
//XML Object which comes after loading XML successfully
var objXml;

function startXMLLoading() {
    //Create New Request
    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
        //This Code runs in IE9, IE10, IE11
        xhttp = new XDomainRequest();
        isXDomain = true;
        //XDomainRequest runs Synchronously, So onload function is necessary
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/xml");
            objXml = xmlDoc;
            //Handle XML Response
            handleXML(objXml);
        };
        xhttp.onerror = function() {};
        xhttp.onprogress = function() {};
        xhttp.open("get", xml_link);
        xhttp.send();

    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Runs in advanced browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (!isXDomain) {
        try {
            //Open Get Request , Synchronous
            xhttp.open("GET", xml_link, true);
            //Callback
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        //Establish Reference to XML Response
                        objXml = xhttp.responseXML;
                        //Handle XML Response
                        handleXML(objXml);
                    }
                }
                //Send Request
                xhttp.send();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("err : " + e);
        }
    }
}

//function for parsing XML object
function handleXML(sXml) {
    //Use Following Syntax to get values of XML Element and Attributes.
    //Only Following Syntax works across all Browsers including IE9, IE10, IE11
    //Syntax like sXml.getElementsByTagName("dataset")[0].children[0].innerHTML doesnot work in IE9,10,11 Browsers 
    //sXml.getElementsByTagName("dataset")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //sXml.getElementsByTagName("dataset")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('voteField');    
}

//window.onload = function(){
startXMLLoading();
//}
```